# include one attribute of other collection in mongoid rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid

I want to query with mongoid , I have following models

```
class Score
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :value, :type => Integer
   belongs_to :user
end


class User
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, :type => String
   field :age, :type => Integer
   has_many :scores
```

I want to query all the scores from collection with their users. but users object should have only have the 'name' field in it

I would be something like

```
   Score.find.all.includes(:user).only(:name)
```

Please tell the correct syntax for this

Answer (score 1):

`Score` references `User`, so it is not possible to retrieve them both in one query, because there are no joins in MongoDB.

Either denormalize and include user name in `Score` or do several queries.

Comment: Map/Reduce can't operate across collections. It's constrained to one.

Comment: True, but... when objects are referenced, one bears the id of the other. So user can do a map/reduce to get user_ids from Scores then query on User.

Comment: You don't need map-reduce for that. And it's still several queries.

Comment: Ypu don't need it but it's the fastest. It's two queries but it works and is extra info to your answer. Just a comment.

Comment: map-reduce is the fastest? Are we talking about the same DB? :)

Comment: Well, To be more precise, it's not the fastest in itself but it doesn't block other read connections on the collection, so it's fastest overall.

Comment: Reads are not blocking in mongodb. Writes are. Map-Reduce does not only read, it writes as well. In addition to write locks, it also has JS locks. So if you run several MRs, you will be quite surprised :)

Comment: Very interesting discussion making me dig into map reduce performance, +1